# What happens in emacs if exiting emacsclient with C-x C-c?

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I've been trying to get used to using `emacsclient` because the load time is so much quicker than always running a full-fledged emacs process every time I want to open a file. I noticed in the emacs manual, it's suggested that I use `C-x #` to exit emacsclient. I'm so used to `C-x C-c` to exit that I often forget.

Is this a problem if I use `C-x C-c` to exit? Is there anything bad that can happen (e.g. corrupted files, zombie processes, etc.)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317065/emacs-client-difference-between-c-x-k-and-c-x/21318293#21318293 but that same answer more or less applies here: Just read the built-in help for `C-x #`.

Comment: But no, nothing **bad** happens if you exit the client with `C-x C-c`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a problem if I use C-x C-c to exit?

No, is this not a problem.